The host XYZ doesn't support Safari version 6.0.4
I made a website a few months ago, I just asked my friend to open my website on his phone, and he said your website is down but actually it was not down after some checking I went to web-check.xyz and saw where it was saying (in TLS simulation tab)
The host www.orbisdev.co does not support Safari version 6  

can someone help me understand it is a Next JS problem or an issue from my DNS?

Meta:
next.config.mjs
import createMDX from "@next/mdx";

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // Configure `pageExtensions` to include markdown and MDX files
  pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "md", "mdx", "ts", "tsx"]
  // Optionally, add any other Next.js config below
};

const withMDX = createMDX({
  // Add markdown plugins here, as desired
});

// Merge MDX config with Next.js config
export default withMDX(nextConfig);

"next": "14.2.5",
"react": "^18",

Hosted on vercel

The issue is likely due to the versions of TLS Vercel supports (TLS 1.2 & 1.3)
Safari 6 (which is pretty old) only supports TLS 1.0. You should not downgrade your TLS to a lower, deprecated version. Your friend needs to upgrade their browser to a modern, more secure version.
